# 90's action movie about two guys running away from evil organisation

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

First of all some information before I go on to write the stuff I remember.
I have watched this movie **two times**, both times it was on some random TV channel. First time I watched it was about 10 years ago, and the second was about 5 years ago. Both times I started watching somewhere from the middle, so I think I know the second part of the movie pretty well.

- Time period: 90's
- Genre: action (with, if I remember correctly, some comedic moments)
- Language: english (from this I also assume that it's made in USA)
- It's a live action movie
- It's in color
- No famous actors

### Premise

There are two (good) guys who are being chased by some organization (or maybe even government, but more likely evil organization) and their thugs. It's because one of the guys is I think enhanced in some way that make him stronger than an average human.

### About the guys

*White guy:*
One of the guys is white, short black/dark hair, wears a black shirt. He is the one I said is enhanced in some way that makes him stronger/more agile than an average human. Because of that he is pretty good at fighting. I think that the organization that is chasing them could be the reason why he is enhanced but I'm not sure, since I didn't watch the first part of the movie.

*Black guy:*
The other guy is black, with black/dark short dreadlocks, wears a brown (probably leather) jacket. He is the one that sometimes makes comedic moments. He is the one driving them, in his red car.

The guys, I think, don't know each other at the start, since there are some arguments between them throughout the movie. Over their journey they gain more and more trust in each other and are friends at the end.
Also when there is fighting (and there is a lot, it's an action movie) the white guy is the one doing the most fighting. The black guy is often a liability due to his lack in fighting skills, but can sometimes help when it's important.

*About the thugs:*
The thugs in this movie are typical, easily replacable, bad at fighting, carry firearms.
Their leader though, is iconic. It's because he always wears a brown cowboy hat, has long wavy hair, bad teeth I think, and maybe has a toothpick all the time (he is the type of character that would have a toothpick all the time).

### **Scenes**

*At black guys' (or his wifes') home:*
There is a scene where they go to black guys' (or his wifes') house because they need something. There the white guy sees a framed family picture of black guy, his (ex) wife and their child/children. I think that from this scene we see that the black guy has/had family issues and problems with his wife (that's why I'm not sure if she is his ex or is about to become).

*In a car:*
There is a scene where the two guys are traveling through some dry/deserty area in a car. I remember it because the black guy bragged about his 19XX year (insert stuff like V8 engine and similar car specification) red muscle car.

*At the motel:*
They stopped in some typical american roadside motel (in the dry/desert area probably), to spend the night I think. At the motel there was a girl that worked there that one (both) of the guys liked (if it's the both case, then they for sure had an argument about it). The next day thugs came and completely destroyed the motel. There was some fighting but the guys eventually escaped.

*At some garage:*
I'm not sure about this, but this garage could be in a previous mentioned motel. There was a fight scene in that garage, I remember the guys using some tires, and some car (not the red one) for cover. They also used some car repair tools for fighting.

*At some factory (?):*
This one is a little blurry in my memory. If I remember correctly there was some open mine factory or something like that. There was a fight scene where the guys fought the thugs on some metal platforms. There were some pipes here and there. I remember it being in the open/outside. The metal platforms and stairs were either yellow or blue.

### **Ending:**

It's night time and the guys come to this nasa/space/apollo themed bar (also in dry/deserty area). The bar has a lot of neon lights inside and outside. Outside there is even a big model of some rocket or space shuttle.

The guys are in that bar and all of a sudden bad guys come inside violently (some even with motorcycles crashing throug the windows (note: the motorcycles are that dirt type, for offroad)). The fighting starts and after some time and good fighting the good guys win.

Then when they think it's finally over, in bar enters this one man never seen before. The fighting starts and this new bad guy has the upper hand. We realize that he is also enhanced in a way our white guy is, maybe even much better enhanced (like some newer technology or something). Anyway the bad guy is much better to some point when our guys realize something and that's when they gain the upper hand and beat him (this one is a little blurry but I have two memories of this, either our guy found some new inner strength, or they beat him by teamwork, I really can't remember).

At the very end I remember them running away from the bar and the whole place explodes. Then the black guy throws some funny comments and they walk off (in  such a manner like "ok we beat this guy, they don't have anything more to send at us").

Comment: The description was a pleasure to read. I feel that it accurately reflects the spirit of the movie.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you, it's really nice to hear that :)

Comment: It was such a good description, I recognised the film straight away and felt compelled to create an account just to post the answer :) I loved this film when I was younger.

Comment: @Tilbs And thank you for it :) I wanted to ask about it for quite some time now, but I din't want to rush it and forget some important parts. I agree, it's a pretty good movie.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds very much like [Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_(1997_film)), with Mark Dacascos and Kadeem Hardison.

> A machine/human-hybrid prototype formerly working for the Red Chinese, Toby Wong (Dacascos), forces a down-on-his-luck, extroverted songwriter named Malik Brody (Hardison) to drive him to Los Angeles after their first meeting in a bar. He is on the run from hitmen—a hillbilly assassin/bounty hunter named Vic Madison and his inane henchman called "Hedgehog".